# Error in implementation of MD5 algorithm in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, implementation

I have written the following implementation of MD5 algorithm. However, the hash values do not match that from online generators.

Correct MD5 Hash of `"testing"` is `"ae2b1fca515949e5d54fb22b8ed95575"`

But my program gives `"786fc25092f719e0349ed15efcbe8460"`

Where is my mistake here?

## Code

Explanation: import necessary libraries and set constants

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word
import Data.Char
import Text.Printf  -- For pretty output of hexdigest
import qualified Data.Array as A
type Numbers = (Word32, Word32, Word32, Word32)
roundShift = A.listArray (0, 63) [7,12,17,22,7,12,17,22,7,12,17,22,7,12,17,22,5,9,14,20,5,9,14,20,5,9,14,20,5,9,14,20,4,11,16,23,4,11,16,23,4,11,16,23,4,11,16,23,6,10,15,21,6,10,15,21,6,10,15,21,6,10,15,21]
sines = A.listArray (0, 63) [ 0xd76aa478, 0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee, 0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a, 0xa8304613, 0xfd469501, 0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be, 0x6b901122, 0xfd987193, 0xa679438e, 0x49b40821, 0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340, 0x265e5a51, 0xe9b6c7aa, 0xd62f105d, 0x02441453, 0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8, 0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6, 0xf4d50d87, 0x455a14ed, 0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8, 0x676f02d9, 0x8d2a4c8a, 0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681, 0x6d9d6122, 0xfde5380c, 0xa4beea44, 0x4bdecfa9, 0xf6bb4b60, 0xbebfbc70, 0x289b7ec6, 0xeaa127fa, 0xd4ef3085, 0x04881d05, 0xd9d4d039, 0xe6db99e5, 0x1fa27cf8, 0xc4ac5665, 0xf4292244, 0x432aff97, 0xab9423a7, 0xfc93a039, 0x655b59c3, 0x8f0ccc92, 0xffeff47d, 0x85845dd1, 0x6fa87e4f, 0xfe2ce6e0, 0xa3014314, 0x4e0811a1, 0xf7537e82, 0xbd3af235, 0x2ad7d2bb, 0xeb86d391 ]  
-- Tables found in Wiki
```

Explanation: Conversions

```
convertToW32 :: (Word8, Word8, Word8, Word8) -> Word32
convertToW32 (a,b,c,d) = (fromIntegral a) + shiftL (fromIntegral b) 8 + shiftL (fromIntegral c) 16 + shiftL (fromIntegral d) 24
convertToW8s :: Int -> Word64 -> [Word8]
convertToW8s 0 w = [fromIntegral w]
convertToW8s n w = let (p, q) = w `quotRem` (256 ^ n) in fromIntegral p : convertToW8s (n - 1) q
```

Explanation: prepare input string into chunks

```
preprocess :: String -> [Word8] 
preprocess message = map (fromIntegral . ord) message ++ padding ++ (convertToW8s 7 . byteSwap64 $ fromIntegral ln)
    where ln = length message
          padding = 0x80 : replicate ((55 - ln) `mod` 64) 0x00


-- required 512-bit input, return array (0, 15)
chunkize :: [Word8] -> [A.Array Int Word32]
chunkize [] = []
chunkize xs = if length xs < 64 
              then error "Cannot form chunk!"
              else A.listArray (0, 15) (bulkConvert p) : chunkize q
                where (p, q) = splitAt 64 xs
                      bulkConvert [] = []
                      bulkConvert (a:b:c:d:r) = convertToW32 (a,b,c,d) : bulkConvert r
```

Explanation: run the loop mentioned in Wiki, for each chunk

```
findABCD :: Numbers -> A.Array Int Word32 -> Numbers 
findABCD tt m = foldl loop tt [0..63]
    where loop t@(a,b,c,d) x = let (f,g,i) = fgi t x in (d, b + rotateL (a + f + sines A.! i + m A.! g) (roundShift A.! i), b, c)

fgi :: Numbers -> Int -> (Word32, Int, Int)
fgi (a, b, c, d) i
    |  0 <= i && i <= 15 = ((b .&. c) .|. ((complement b) .&. d), i, i)
    | 16 <= i && i <= 31 = ((d .&. b) .|. ((complement d) .&. c), (1 + 5 * i) `mod` 16, i)
    | 32 <= i && i <= 47 = (b `xor` c `xor` d, (5 + 3 * i) `mod` 16, i)
    | 48 <= i && i <= 63 = (c `xor` ((complement d) .|. b), (7 * i) `mod` 16, i)
    | otherwise = error "Index exceeds range!"
```

Explanation: md5sum of string; main is just a caller function

```
md5 :: String -> String
md5 message = printf "%08x%08x%08x%08x" a0 b0 c0 d0
    where (a0, b0, c0, d0) = foldl addToResult (0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 0x10325476) (chunkize $ preprocess message)
          addToResult t@(a, b, c, d) arr = let (a', b', c', d') = findABCD t arr in (a + a', b + b', c + c', d + d')

main = putStrLn . md5 =<< getLine
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to take apart one of the existing correct MD5 implementations to get the intermediate states and compare them to what your program produces. (For example, when I did this, I had endless trouble getting the padding to exactly match the RFC.) For example, there's a Haskell package called `pureMD5` which you might be able to take apart and compare values against.

Comment: Your length, `ln`, should be in bits not bytes .  First get the empty string working. Then one character, then two, then a full block, then a block plus one character.  After that you'll want to look for corner cases around padding.

Comment: The length is supposed to be 64 bits, but you used only 32.   The values are all supposed to be little endian but you are 1. Using big endian for the pad 2. using big endian in the output.

Comment: I thought `replicate (1 +` here accounts for 32 bits of length in integer; another 32 bits from `fromIntegral ln` makes a total of 64. Is there any libraries for endianness conversion or I need to write my own?

Comment: Ok let's try saying this again.  `0x80000000 /= 0x00000080` which would be the little endian representation.  Also, I doubt you actually want each character expanded to 32 bits as you have done in preprocess.  When I fix the problems noted in these comments things work for my few tests.

Comment: Wrt libraries you can use cereal or binary.

Comment: Oh no?  Have you gotten bored?  If you need more real-time discussion then feel free to ask on irc.freenode.net #haskell.

Comment: Out of town for a while. I reworked the code a bit converting everything to Word8. Still I guess there is endianness problem for function `md5`. I'd be glad to know if `preprocess` code is right though.